# PrestaShop: hook on close customer thread

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I need to make a module to send an e-mail when a customer thread is closed. To do that I'm thinking on use a hook when a Customer Thread is updated, then I can check the status and perform the actions I need.

Using the [validator.prestashop.com](https://validator.prestashop.com/) I found the `actionObjectCustomerThreadAddAfter`. I would like to know if there is a similar hook to when I close or update a Thread. The only hook list I found so far in [this one](http://www.prestarocket.com/blog/prestashop-1-7-hook-list-liste-des-hooks/) but even this hook I found doesn't exist there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every class that extends `ObjectModel` and uses its `add()`, `update()`, `delete()` or `save()` methods you have the following hooks available for use.

```
actionObjectAddBefore
actionObjectNameAddBefore
actionObjectAddAfter
actionObjectNameAddAfter

actionObjectUpdateBefore
actionObjectNameUpdateBefore
actionObjectUpdateAfter
actionObjectNameUpdateAfter

actionObjectDeleteBefore
actionObjectNameDeleteBefore
actionObjectDeleteAfter
actionObjectNameDeleteAfter
```

Replace `Name` with the name of class. All of these hooks also pass the object itself as parameter.

```
array(
    'object' => $this
)
```

So for customer thread status you can use `actionObjectCustomerThreadUpdateBefore` and `actionObjectCustomerThreadUpdateAfter` hooks to detect if status was changed and send email.

**Edit**

And then you find gems like this in admin customer thread controller.

```
if ($id_status = (int)Tools::getValue('setstatus')) {
     $status_array = array(1 => 'open', 2 => 'closed', 3 => 'pending1', 4 => 'pending2');
     Db::getInstance()->execute('
        UPDATE '._DB_PREFIX_.'customer_thread
        SET status = "'.$status_array[$id_status].'"
        WHERE id_customer_thread = '.(int)$id_customer_thread.' LIMIT 1
    ');
}
```

Meaning that it doesn't use object to save status but direct call to database so the hooks never execute.

You will have to override `AdminCustomerThreadsController` and its `postProcess()` method to add your code.

Comment: Thanks, that's a really useful info to have! As soon as I implement I will give the feedback and mark the answer as right.

Comment: I added and it looks like the code is not reached. I see the hook in the hook table but when I go to the Manage Hooks section I can't see it there. What can I be doing wrong?

Comment: @AndréLuiz Did you tick `Display non-positionable hooks`? Also make sure you register those hooks in the install method of the module.

Comment: you are right, it appears there but it seems not to be executing, I'm investigating. The function : public function hookActionObjectCustomerThreadUpdateAfter($params){open("/Users/andredx/Projects/testfile.txt", "w");}

Comment: @AndréLuiz Sadly you will not be able to use hooks for customer thread status update. I explained it in the edited answer.

Comment: you are right. I'm overriding then. Thanks for taking the time to help me!